# How to parse JSON in JAVA without knowing the contents of the JSON file

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to do a program that gets the file info from the path and parse it without knowing the information inside it.

I know there is a `jo.get("name");`way for example but if i dont know the "name" variable how should i split the file? Our file will contain hundreds of variables like "name" "address" "city" etc.

Comment: All you can do (and what common JSON libraries would most likely do by default) is read it into a `Map<String, Object>` (where the value could be another nested map). Not sure how much processing you can do on that but at least you can read the map keys to identify the names.

Answer (score 1):

As was suggested in the comments, you can convert JSON into Map. Here is the example how to do that: https://www.javatpoint.com/convert-json-to-map-in-java
After that you may work with your map like that:

```
System.out.println("Name : " + userData.get("Name"));  
System.out.println("Mobile : " + userData.get("Mobile"));  
System.out.println("Designation : " + userData.get("Designation"));  
System.out.println("Pet : " + userData.get("Pet"));  
System.out.println("Address : " + userData.get("Address"));
```

Comment: in this link the key values are known and there is just 5 of them. in my json files the key values is more than 1000+ is there easier way to get all key values?

Comment: @opsy you parse JSON into MAP, then you can get all the keys from the map using Map.keySet() method: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashmap-keyset-method-in-java/